Can't create a new project: spawn EINVAL
I'm trying to create a new project with NativeScript and Angular.
I have installed what is described here.
When I run the command tns doctor everything is fine. There it is the result:
✔ Getting environment information

No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.7.0 version and is up to date.

But when I run tns create after setting the name and the type (Angular) of the project then I select the Hello World template, it gives me
spawn EINVAL

Is there a solution?
I'm using Windows 11.
node -v
v20.12.2
npm -v
10.5.2

EDIT
I run this command
tns build android --log trace

And now I have these info:
Failed to build plugin @nativescript/core :
Error: spawn EINVAL
Error: Failed to build plugin @nativescript/core : 
Error: spawn EINVAL
    at Errors.failWithOptions (C:\Users\giada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:165:27)
    at Errors.fail (C:\Users\giada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:137:21)
    at AndroidPluginBuildService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\giada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\android-plugin-build-service.js:508:30)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\giada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\android-plugin-build-service.js:12:65)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

In addition, I downgraded npm. Now I have the 10.3.0 version

I solved this in a strange way. It seems that the new installations of  nodejs doesn't copy all of the modules that nativescript needs to run. So... I copied the node_modules folder from a pc that had installed nodejs in the past and paste that folder in my node_modules under the %appdata% path.

Thank you for your workaround. I've posted by workaround below. Hopefully a fix will be pushed soon.

The problem seems to be related to an CVE that requires node to pass: { shell: true } in the child_process.spawn options. This vulnerability fix only applies on node 18, 20 and 21.
Wednesday, April 10, 2024 Security Releases
I solved it by downgrading to node 16 and wait for an update of nativescript.
