Can't build Nativescript + Angular app: inspector_modules doesn't exist
My colleague has created a project with NativeScript + Angular.
She has pushed the project in the git-repo and then I cloned it on my machine.
I installed everything under this guide but when i run tns build android it throws me this error:
ERROR in tns_modules/inspector_modules
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/core/inspector_modules' in 'C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp'
resolve '@nativescript/core/inspector_modules' in 'C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\node_modules
        existing directory C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\node_modules\@nativescript\core
          using description file: C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\node_modules\@nativescript\core\package.json (relative path: .)
            using description file: C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\node_modules\@nativescript\core\package.json (relative path: ./inspector_modules)
              no extension
                C:\Repository\Solutions\RaptorApp\RaptorApp\node_modules\@nativescript\core\inspector_modules doesn't exist
              .android.ts

and it lists many other file with same path\name but different extensions.
The command tns doctor said it's all fine.
How can i resolve this?

This looks like the same issue as mentioned here. Essentially a recent update of @nativescript/webpack caused this. If you have dependency that allows patch updates (e.g "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.0"), you might have gotten this update after a ns clean.
It has been fixed now in version 5.0.20, so try to update the version, or lock the version to 5.0.18.

Thanks, I forced that version. Now I have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78335654/cant-create-a-new-project-spawn-einval . Do you have any ideas?

Sorry for the late response, but I see you have found a workaround to the problem in your comment!
Perhaps you could accept my answer to this question if it helped you?
